# PHP - How to use information appended to a URL

Tags: php

Suppose I have a website

www.game.com

Now on this website there is a list of players and when I click on a specific player it takes me to:

www.game.com/stats.php?id=1

Say I go back and click a different player and it takes me to

www.game.com/stats.php?id=2

I need a way for parse_url to extract the values '1' and '2' uniquely when those players are clicked.
If i type out parse_url('http://www.game.com/stats.php?id=2') 
This will not work. I need 1 statement that works dynamically to extract that id number and store it in a variable on the stats.php page whenever a players name is clicked.
When a new stats page is loaded the variable is just updated with the new ID and information from my database can be pulled by it.

Thoughts?

Comment: $id=(int)$_GET['id'];

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort.  A Google search for "php url parameters" brings up http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php as the very first result.

Comment: lol well excuse me for being new to stack overflow. How do you know I haven't researched this for hours and couldn't find the right answer so I decided to ask it here?

Comment: It took me less than 30 seconds to google.  That's how i know.

Comment: because whatever you enter: variable in the url using php or how to get variables in the URL using php or many other ways, google will give you relevant results that will surely help

Comment: @cHao well clearly you knew exactly what to google and I did not. Thanks for your help! Not.

Comment: Hey, i linked the page that explains it.  But just for curiosity's sake, what were you googling for hours that didn't turn up any info, and didn't at least guide you toward what you *should* be looking for?

Comment: To be fair, if you are completely new to PHP and to web development, you probably will not know that the things after that question mark in the URL are called parameters, so you may not know what to google...

Comment: @rob74: Even the top two results for "php question mark in url" explain how `$_GET` works.

Answer (score 1):

These pieces of information appended to the URL are called GET parameters. In PHP, you can access them using the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array:

```
$id = $_GET['id'] // -> 1 or 2
```

or you can use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), which includes GET and POST parameters and cookies.

Both of these arrays are [superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), so you can use them in functions without declaring them as global.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP GET:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php